# What are pros and cons of UK Building Societies compared to banks?

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage

I have learnt a bit about the history of building societies in the UK, but what are their advantages and disadvantages compared to banks today?

I get the impressions that they may be willing to issue mortgages with smaller deposits, but may take longer to make a decision. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> they may be willing to issue mortgages with smaller deposits, but may take longer to make a decision

That cannot be farther from the truth. If you are getting a mortgage on a smaller deposit, you will be paying a higher interest rate. Time to take a decision depends very much on your credit situation, earnings, spending and the amount of loan you want to avail of.

> advantages and disadvantages compared to banks today

Nothing specifically that is obvious. You deposits are guaranteed by FSCS, which is primarily everybody's biggest concern. One thing I did observe was they generally have saving accounts which pay better than the big banks, but that is for one to compare and find out.

In ownership structure you own a part of the building society because you are a member by having an account(bank/mortgage) with them. Not the case with a big bank though unless you own any shares. You can make a case for the difference of the big bank's multiple business as compared to a building society.